# Getting all diagonals from top right to bottom left in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to store all the diagonals in the matrix from the top right to the bottom left and store them in an array.

```py
matrix = array([[2, 0, 0, 2],
                [3, 0, 0, 3],
                [3, 0, 0, 2],
                [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Expected ouptut**

```py
[
 [2],
 [0, 3],
 [0, 0, 2],
 [2, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 0, 0],
 [3, 0],
 [0]
]
```

What I tried to do was this code:
However, this will get me all the diagonals from top left to bottom right

```py
def get_diags_lower_left(matrix):
    return [np.fliplr(matrix).diagonal(i) for i in range(-3, 4)][::-1]
```

Comment: @diggusbickus it doest give the expected output

Comment: it does give the expected output, don't flip the matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generalized solution that works on any MxN matrix:

```
[matrix.diagonal(i) for i in range(-matrix.shape[0] + 1, matrix.shape[1])][::-1]
```

output:

```
[array([2]),
 array([0, 3]),
 array([0, 0, 2]),
 array([2, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([3, 0, 0]),
 array([3, 0]),
 array([0])]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not flip the matrix it works. Using:

```py
def get_diags_lower_left(matrix):
    return [matrix.diagonal(i) for i in range(-3, 4)][::-1]
```

Will yield:

```
[array([2]),
 array([0, 3]),
 array([0, 0, 2]),
 array([2, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([3, 0, 0]),
 array([3, 0]),
 array([0])
]
```

Comment: How I could miss that, you are right!