# How to obtain bottom diagonals of a matrix according to an index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like to know how it is possible to obtain the diagonals that point downwards (left and right) with respect to a specific index of the matrix.

To be more graphic I will give the following example of an expected output:

```py
matrix = np.array([[2, 0, 0, 2],
                  [3, 9, 8, 3],
                  [3, 0, 0, 2],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Expected output results for position:** `matrix[1][2]`

```py
matrix[1][2]
8

diag_right = [2]
diag_left  = [0, 0]
```

Same example but using the matrix in matrix[1][2]

```py
matrix = np.array([[x, x, x, x],
                   [x, x, 8, x],
                   [x, 0, x, 2],
                   [0, x, x, x]])
```

Comment: you want what? that's not clear at all. Please reformule, what are all the diagonals that  you except? what have you tried?

Comment: @UlisesBussi check the second sample, maybe you can let me know what you are not understanding. I tried this code from my previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886991/getting-all-diagonals-from-top-right-to-bottom-left-in-array

Comment: I think I understand now... let me see: you want to access a function with the matrix and the coords of some value (i.e. 1 ,2) and get both diagonals? that is easyest than your last problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way using numpy would be:
(i've changed the matrix to make more clear some results in test_ij)

```
import numpy as np

def get_right_left_diags(matrix,i,j):
    n = len(matrix)
    left_diag  = np.diag(matrix[i+1:n,j+1:n])
    right_diag = np.diag( matrix[i+1:n, j-1::-1])
    return right_diag,left_diag

%lets check some results
matrix = np.array([[2, 0, 0, 2],
                  [3, 9, 8, 3],
                  [3, 0, 0, 2],
                  [1, 2, 3, 4]])

n = len(matrix)

cases = [[0,0],[0,3],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]]
for i,j in cases:
    right_diag,left_diag = get_right_left_diags(matrix,i,j)
    print(f"i={i}, j={j}, left_diag: {left_diag} \t right_diag: {right_diag}")
```

this will output:

```
#i=0, j=0, left_diag: [9 0 4]    right_diag: [3 0 2]
#i=0, j=3, left_diag: []     right_diag: [8 0 1]
#i=1, j=1, left_diag: [0 4]      right_diag: [3]
#i=1, j=2, left_diag: [2]    right_diag: [0 1]
#i=2, j=1, left_diag: [3]    right_diag: [1]
```

for me it has total sense.

Comment: Both answers are right, but I tested the efficiency in both process and this one is faster.

Comment: makes sense the other option uses a for and some apendings, the numpy indexing is faster than that

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = np.array([[2, 0, 0, 2],
                  [3, 9, 8, 3],
                  [3, 0, 0, 2],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])

i = 1; j = 2
diag_right = []; diag_left = []

for k in range(1, len(matrix) - i):
    if(j+k < len(matrix[0])):
        diag_right.append(matrix[i+k][j+k])
    if(j-k >= 0):
        diag_left.append(matrix[i+k][j-k])
```

Is this what you're looking for?